# Cannot read property PushNotification of undefined

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I'm getting error

> cannot read property PushNotification of undefined

I have included all the required script file. Please help.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#login', function(){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var pushNotification ;

        try {
            pushNotification = window.plugins.PushNotification;
            alert("android");
            pushNotification.register(successHandler , errorHandler, { "senderID": "619025542236", "ecb": "onNotificationGCM" });    // required!
        }  
        catch (err) {
            txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
            txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";

            //console.log(txt);
            alert(txt);
        }
        function successHandler(result) {
            alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
        }
        function errorHandler(error) {
            alert(error);
        }


        function onNotificationGCM(e) {
            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                    if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                    {
                        console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                        $.post("http://dashboard.kanalytics.in/kore/webservices/dashboard_gcm_insert.php",
                        {
                            regid : e.regid,
                            name : "",

                            //name:"rohit",
                            //email:"jiten.ktm@gmail.com"
                        });
                        alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
                    }
                    break;

                case 'message':
                    // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                    alert('message = '+e.message);
                    var message = document.getElementById(e.message);
                    window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Dashboard Notification", e.message);
                    var sound = new Media("assets/www/"+e.sounds);
                    sound.play();   
                    break;

                case 'error':
                    alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
                    break;

                default:
                    alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to listen to the cordova deviceready-event: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html

Comment: thanks for reply Joerg now i have included cordova deviceready-event but now getting the error "cannot call method register of undefined" what will be the  issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not added the PushNotification plugin to the Cordova project and that is why the pushNotification object is undefined.